# django-webtest Testing URLs on a page

Tags: django, python-2.7, webtest

How to get a list of all links on a page using django-webtest?

In my case, i want to test that users have appropriate urls on a page, according to their permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think i found out how to get a list of all the urls on a page:

```
assert False, response.click(verbose=True)
```

This will print all the url elements that webtest found on a page with a feedback if it was accepted or skipped.